# Div background color flashing white before animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have an animated header button that uses jQuery, jQuery UI, the jQuery UI color plugin, CSS, and HTML. An example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNp5x/.

The following is the HTML markup that I am using:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header_label">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is a simple header that has a button inside of it, called `header_label`.

Here is the jQuery I am using to animate the `header_label` div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header_label").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".header_label").animate({
            borderLeftWidth: "8px",
            backgroundColor: "#2778ff"
        }, 300);
    });
    $(".header_label").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            borderLeftWidth: "2px",
            backgroundColor: "#27AEFF"
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

As you can see, I am using the `backgroundColor` attribute in the `.animate()` function. The jQuery Color plugin enables this.

The styles for the div elements is as follows:

```
.header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #27AEFF;
}
.header_label {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 32px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

As you can see when you mouse over the header button, it flashes white before changing to its intended color, `#2778ff`. Also, it only flashes white the first time you mouse over the `header_label`.

How do I make the `.header_label` div change to its intended color without flashing white?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Chrome-only issue. Adding

> background:#27AEFF;

to .header_label as well as .header seems to fix it.

My guess for why this happens is that without having a starting colour specified, it doesn't know what colour to change *from* when you first rollover, and so defaults to white.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I will accept the answer as soon as it will let me.